# Оптимизация рекурсии трассировки лучей

Tags: c#, .net-5, raytracing

Играюсь с [примером софтварной реализации трассировки лучей](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/samples/dotnet/samples/parallel-programming-winforms-raytracer-cs/) от майкрософта. На самом деле пример про многопоточность, но меня в нём привлек именно алгоритм 3D рендера.

Вот метод. Если бы это была хвостовая рекурсия, я бы легко справился, но здесь пока не могу.

```cs
using System.Numerics;
```

```
private const int maxDepth = 6;

private Vector3 TraceRay(Ray ray, Scene scene, int depth)
{
    (SceneObject obj, float distance) = ClosestIntersection(ray, scene);
    if (obj is null)
        return Vector3.Zero;

    Vector3 pos = distance * ray.Direction + ray.Start;
    Vector3 normal = obj.Normal(pos);
    Vector3 reflectDir = Vector3.Reflect(ray.Direction, normal);
    Vector3 color = GetNaturalColor(obj, pos, normal, reflectDir, scene);

    if (depth >= maxDepth)
        return color;

    // типы =              float                     Vector3
    return color + obj.Surface.Reflect(pos) * obj.Surface.Diffuse(pos) * TraceRay(new Ray(pos, reflectDir), scene, depth + 1);
}
```

Изначальный вызов:

```cs
Vector3 color = TraceRay(new Ray(camera.Pos, GetPoint(x, y, camera)), scene, 0);
```

Возможна ли линейная оптимизация без выделения дополнительной памяти? Или с выделением, но чтобы оно хотя-бы чуть-чуть быстрее заработало.

*Я не буду показывать вызываемые отсюда методы и свои структуры данных, они на суть вопроса не влияют. Но если надо - пишите, добавлю в вопрос.*

---

Вот луч.

```cs
readonly ref struct Ray
{
    public readonly Vector3 Start;
    public readonly Vector3 Direction;

    public Ray(Vector3 start, Vector3 direction)
    {
        Start = start;
        Direction = direction;
    }
}
```

Кстати, формулу цвета пикселя я вывел такую

```
c0 + r0 * (c1 + r1 * (c2 + r2 * (c3 + r3 * (c4 + r4 * (c5 + r5 * (c6))))))
```

`cN` - цвет объекта с учетом освещения
`rN` - коэффициенты отражения
`N` - итерация

Comment: ¿Мне кажется, или рекурсия и создание новых объектов Ray на каждом уровне вложенности ни к чему?

Comment: @user7860670 `Ray` - это `ref struct` двумя векторами внутри. Менял на кортеж, на простые аргументы, разницы никакой. А от рекурсии я и сам бы избавился, но пока не сообразил, как именно. Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: “Играюсь с примером софтварной реализации”
“высокая алгоритмическая распараллеливаемость вычислений — можно параллельно и независимо трассировать два и более лучей,”
Тут так и просятся шейдеры GPU радикально поднимет скорость а не  «хотя-бы чуть-чуть быстрее заработало.”

Comment: @barsik34566 само собой, но цель не в этом, а в изучении самого алгоритма и основ трехмерной графики. И да, хоть и софтварно, но это все завернуто в потоки, так что все ядра гружу под максимум (анимация с летающими сферами по сцене). Сам `Vector3` ездит на SIMD инструкциях. Я пока ищу именно оптимальную реализацию, а не подходящие инструменты. OpenGL/DirectX никуда не убегут, и до них доберусь. :)

Comment: Не обидно ли вам будет от того что например на javasсript быдлокодом в браузере на webgl такой простой код трассировки нагнет в  больше 1000 раз  по скорости ваш лучший оптимизированный алгоритм с SIMD? 

Берите сразу правильные инструменты.

Comment: @barsik34566 да я алгоритм изучаю, а не боевой рендерер пишу. Относительно исходного примера от Microsoft мне уже удалось поднять производительность в 10 раз. И алгоритм я учу как раз в процессе оптимизации и рефакторинга кода, метод изучения у меня такой, всегда работает.

Comment: Хм.. А разве здесь не хвостовая рекурсия??? Простой цикл от maxDepth до нуля.

Comment: @MBo не хвостовая, обратите внимание на `pos` и `reflectDir`, вычисляемые в текущей и передаваемые в следующую итерацию. Грубо говоря я пускаю луч из камеры, он отражается от объектов до тех пор, пока не достигнет максимальной глубины рекурсии или улетит в космос (не найдет препятствия), и далее от конца к началу я складываю цвета, за счет этого и получается отражение. То есть от начала к концу прокладывается маршрут луча, а от конца к началу рендерится пиксель. Я уже понял, что без скорее всего без выделения памяти не обойтись, но попробую сделать это максимально дешево.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом, магии, как и ожидалось, не найдено.

От рекурсии удалось избавиться, но с выделением памяти...в стеке. :)

```cs
private const int maxDepth = 6;
private const int stackDepth = maxDepth * 2 + 1;

private Vector3 TraceRay(Vector3 start, Vector3 direction, Scene scene)
{
    Span<Vector3> stack = stackalloc Vector3[stackDepth];
    int s = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        (SceneObject obj, float distance) = ClosestIntersection(start, direction, scene);
        if (obj is null)
            break;
        start += distance * direction;
        Vector3 normal = obj.Normal(start);
        direction = Vector3.Reflect(direction, normal);
        stack[s++] = GetNaturalColor(obj, start, normal, direction, scene);

        if (s == stackDepth)
            break;
        stack[s++] = obj.Surface.Reflect(start) * obj.Surface.Diffuse(start);
    }
    Vector3 color = (s & 1) == 1 ? stack[--s] : Vector3.Zero;
    while (s > 0)
    {
        color = color * stack[--s] + stack[--s];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Есть совсем незначительный прирост производительности, почти в рамках погрешности измерений. Но лучшего я ничего пока не придумал.